# How to show and hide loading on Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I have a Fragment where now I'm displaiyng a PDF file with institucional data. It works perfectly, but sometimes depending on the connection speed, it wastes a lot of time to show.
I tried to put a code to show a progressbar, that already exists on xml:

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar_pdf"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:progress="0"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/viewPdf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</WebView>
```

My class is showing completely the pdf files, but when I try to modify to load the progressbar, the screen crashes.
I used OnFinished and On Started methods to manage the timing:

private var _binding: FragmentPdfvisualizadorBinding? = null

```
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private var PDF_VIEWER_URL = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="
private var url: String? = null
private var tipopdf: String? = null
private var i = 0
private var txtView: TextView? = null
private val handler = Handler()    


private var reloadCount = 0
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentPdfvisualizadorBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)       

    return binding.root
}



@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    url = arguments?.getString("urlpdf")
    tipopdf = arguments?.getString("tipopdf")

    val webView = _binding!!.viewPdf
    val texto = _binding!!.labelprogress
    val settings = webView.settings
    val progressbar = _binding!!.progressbar_pdf as ProgressBar

    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    // Enable DOM storage API.
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true

    // Enable zooming in web view.
    settings.setSupportZoom(true)

    // Allow pinch to zoom.
    settings.builtInZoomControls = true

    // Disable the default zoom controls on the page.
    settings.displayZoomControls = false

    // Enable responsive layout.
    settings.useWideViewPort = false

    // Zoom out if the content width is greater than the width of the viewport.
    settings.loadWithOverviewMode = false

    val urlString: String = PDF_VIEWER_URL + url

    
    //webView.webViewClient = DefaultWebViewClient()
    // Checar se pagina foi carregada até o final
    webView.loadUrl(urlString)
    webView.DefaultWebViewClient = DefaultWebViewClient()
    
    Log.d("LOG_TAG_TIPO", "Pdf selecionado: $tipopdf")
    Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Loading URL: $urlString")

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true){
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            Log.d("LOG_FECHOU_FRAGMENT", "Fechou o a tela pdf")
        }
    })
}
private class DefaultWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {

    private var bindi: FragmentPdfvisualizadorBinding? = null
    private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = bindi?.progressbarPdf

    fun DefaultWebViewClient() {
        bindi?.progressbarPdf?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        url: String
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        bindi?.progressbarPdf?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
}
```

As you see, it's a Fragment. I have searched videos showing about Activities. I need this solution to finalyze a project.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: show the stacktrace

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `!!` instead of `?`? `!!` will throw NullPointerException if the value is null, `?` will not.

Comment: @ColeTustin he shouldn't be using neither !! or ?. He should be using the binding val.

Comment: @MACROSystems Agreed, but he is using `!!` everywhere, asking for NPEs.

Comment: @ColeTustin indeed

Comment: @ColeTustin I changed !! to ?, but doesnt work. I'm using bind variable from a private class inside the same kotlin file.

Comment: I have updated the file. I tested on a cell phone, and it show only the WebView native loading for opening files. Im opening from google docs.

Comment: @FabricioFranco You're not initializing `bindi` to a non-null value anywhere. Make `DefaultWebViewClient` an inner class of your fragment and use the fragment's `binding` val instead.